# Triple SLI GTX 680s and a Corsair 860w PSU?

Tags: power-supply, sli

I am planning on running three GTX 680s in SLI mode. Will my 860w Corsair PSU be sufficient to power my GPUs safely? I have read several conflicting accounts on this and would like a clear answer.

**Updated to reflect my system specs:**

Intel Core i7-4790K 4.0GHz Quad-Core Processor

Corsair H75 54.0 CFM Liquid CPU Cooler

Asus MAXIMUS VII HERO ATX LGA1150 Motherboard

2x Corsair Vengeance Pro 16GB (2 x 8GB) DDR3-2400 Memory

Samsung 840 Pro Series 256GB 2.5" Solid State Drive

3x Seagate 2TB Desktop Gaming SSHD SATA 6Gb/s 64MB Cache 3.5-Inch Internal Bare Drive (ST2000DX001)

2x MSI GeForce GTX 680 2GB Video Card (2-Way SLI)

Inwin D-FRAME Red ATX Desktop Case

Corsair 860W 80+ Platinum Certified Fully-Modular ATX Power Supply

Comment: This question should me asked on 
[Hardware Recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and deleted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say, please share the rest of your build. You might be okay limit. You can use part picker for that

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my post to reflect my other system specifications.

Comment: Fill a list in part picker.com then look at the power usage

Comment: I did but, interestingly, partspicker only allowed me two GTX 680s. Could my motherboard be a limiting factor? Asus claims that it can support 3 or 4 way SLI.

Comment: According to the description at newegg its max 2

Comment: What about a single/2 better card

Comment: I already have a 680 from my previous build. I will just add a second card in SLI and skip the 3-way. Thanks for the help!